# Sum involving exp of squared zeros of Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions, zeta-functions

Let $m,n$ be integers, and $j_{n,m}$ be the $m$-th positive zero of the $n$-th Bessel function $J_n$.
How do we compute the sum

$$ \sum_{m=1}^\infty \exp \left( - A \, j_{n,m}^2 \right)$$

for some $A >0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

The approximate zeros of
$J_v$
follow from
the asymptotic expansion

$J_v(z)
=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(z-\frac12 \pi v-\frac14 \pi)
$.

This is zero when
$z-\frac12 \pi v-\frac14 \pi
=\pi n +\frac12 \pi
$
or
$z_{v, n}
=\frac12 \pi v+\frac14 \pi
+\pi n +\frac12 \pi
=\pi(n+\frac12  v+\frac34 )
$.

Since this grows
linearly with $n$,
your $A$ must be negative.

This starts to look like
a theta function
which has a transformation formula
which might enable the sum to be
more conveniently evaluated.

The terms in the sum
get rapidly smaller,
so most of the value
will be contributed
by the first few terms.
These, of course,
are the ones where 
the asymptotic approximation
is least accurate.